# Interview questions for Flash developers

Tags: flash

For an interview in a few, I'm not at all familiar with Flash development.

What would you ask?

Comment: You are asking this question for a Business Application or for a Game business?

Comment: You should change the title to "Interview questions for Flash developers"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, if you yourself aren't a flash developer, I'd caution against interviewing a potential Flash developer, unless you're only doing it to get a sense of their character (as opposed to their skill level). Experience in working with the technology is going to give you a much more realistic perspective - blindly asking questions that other people told you are good ones to ask will get you into trouble.

That said, if you can find someone you know to sit in on the interview with you and provide evaluation from a technical standpoint, here's a few things I'd remind them to ask:

- object oriented programming
- loading external media
- audio & video playback (also maybe volume control / mixing)
- event listeners
- transitions / animation
- filter / sort algorithms
- common UI elements: scrollbar, form elements, drop-down menu, rollover states, drag-and-drop, etc.

Those are sort of generally useful areas of knowlege, but the true test of profficiency is a practical test - "write a class that meets these requirements", or "this code isn't working, find out why and fix it" are good ways to immediately gain insight into the candidate's work (and thought) process.

**Most importantly:** even if the interviewee is short on specific knowlege or experience of the subjects you settle on, it's better to get someone who is a fast learner and will easily comprehend new concepts then to get someone who might know a lot now, but will resist learning new stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Flash can be used for a lot of different purposes. If I was interested in 2D animation, I could use Flash to draw characters, animate scenes, add audio, etc. and not know a lick of programming.

On the flip side, I might need to use flash to make an audio player widget for my website. I'd need to know how to do a fair amount of programming (the name of Flash's programming language is ActionScript), but I might not know anything about vector drawing, design, or animation.

What I'm getting at, is just because someone lists "Flash experience" on their resume doesn't mean they've used flash to do anything close to what you want them to do. If you want a graphic designer, animator, artist, etc. the interview will be much different than if you want someone who can program.

Comment: very good point - I know I'd separate people into Flash Designers and Flash Developers - maybe even Flash Animators as well.

Answer (score 2):

- Explain what a MovieClip in AS2/F8 is. Then go to AS3 and explain the diff between Sprite and Movieclip.
- How to handle keyboard events in AS2? AS3?
- Best way to embed flash into html. Static and dynamic publishing.
- How to make a preloader? Both first-frame and separate
- write a simple clickable button in AS2 and AS3.

This list can go on of course, just some starters.

Comment: keyboard events are a good one. embedding is a good one, though not necessary if you've got another front-end person that's resposible for the html/css/javascript side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Object Oriented?

What do you like in ActionScript3 that ActionScript 2 haven't?

Comment: There is object oriented Flash?

Comment: ctionScript 3.0 is a powerful, object-oriented programming language that signifies an important step in the evolution of the capabilities of the Flash Player runtime. Source here : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html

Comment: You can do OOP AS2 too, to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need them for, I would ask what else they know in conjunction with Flash. If it's for anything on the web, 100% Flash should very rarely be the answer and so it's important to have other skills in the tool belt.

Answer (score 0):

Please give me an example of a time when you used a Flash implementation, and later decided you should have used something else.  What should you have used and why?

Comment: ooh, it's a variation of 'what do you feel your weaknesses are' question!

Answer (score 0):

Please give me an example of a time you implemented an interface in [select a technology] and later decided you should have used Flash.  Explain why Flash would have been the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Flash over other web interface technologies?  Give some examples of when you have used different technologies and why.